# Find all complex solutions to an exponential equation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find all complex numbers z such that $e^{-2iz}/4 + e^{-iz}/2 + 1 + 2e^{iz} + 4e^{2iz} = 0 $

Rewriting the left-hand side using Eulers formula doesn't seem to get me anywhere. Need some help with this one!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $w=2 e^{i z}$.  Then

$$w^2+w+1+\frac{1}{w}+\frac{1}{w^2}=0$$

This can be transformed into

$$\left ( w+\frac{1}{w}\right)^2 + w+\frac{1}{w} -1=0$$

So let $y=w+1/w$ and solve the resulting quadratic:

$$y^2+y-1=0 \implies y= \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2} = \phi_{\pm}$$

Now solve

$$w^2-\phi_{\pm} w + 1=0$$

which implies that

$$w = \frac{\phi_{\pm} \pm \sqrt{\phi_{\pm}^2-4}}{2} = \frac{\phi_{\pm}}{2} \pm i \sqrt{1-\left ( \frac{\phi_{\pm}}{2}\right)^2}$$

Also, you may notice that

$$\frac{\phi_+}{2} = \cos{\frac{2 \pi}{5}}$$
$$\frac{\phi_-}{2} = \cos{\frac{4\pi}{5}}$$

So you can put $w$ into the form $e^{i \theta}$ and solve for $z$ accordingly.  We get 4 solutions for $w$:

$$w_1 = e^{i 2 \pi/5}  = 2 e^{i z_1}$$
$$w_2 = e^{-i 2 \pi/5}= 2 e^{i z_2}$$
$$w_3 = e^{i 4 \pi/5}= 2 e^{i z_3}$$
$$w_4 = e^{-i 4 \pi/5}= 2 e^{i z_4}$$

Solve for the $z$'s using logarithms.  For example,

$$z_1 = \frac{2 \pi}{5} + 2 \pi k_1 + i \log{2}$$

for any $k_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$.  You can do the rest similarly.

Comment: Actually, shouldn't the equation be 1/8w^2 + 1/4w + 1 + w + w^2 = 0 after the substitution?

Comment: @user1176517: no.

Comment: I must be missing something. How did you get rid of the fractions?

Comment: $w=2 e^{i z} \implies (1/4) e^{-i 2 z} = 1/(2 e^{i z})^2 = 1/w^2$.

Comment: Of course, you're right!

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started.  Multiply through by $e^{2iz}$, obtaining

$4e^{4iz} + 2e^{3iz} + e^{2iz} + \frac{1}{2}e^{iz} + \frac{1}{4} = 0$,

then set $w = e^{iz}$, obtaining

$4w^4 + 2w^3 + w^2 + \frac{1}{2}w + \frac{1}{4} =  0$,

multiply by $4$ to make things look nice:

$16w^4 + 8w^3 + 4w^2 + 2w + 1 = 0$.

Now you can solve it as a quartic (from the well -known procedure) and work backwards from there to get $z$ such that $e^{iz} = w$!

Comment: "Well-known procedure"? I doubt it...

Comment: Why doubt that?  It's been around for centuries, going back I think to Cardano, you can get it on wikipdia here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function, and it's seminal to understanding the historical and theoretical underpinnings of.Galois theory.  These observations all lend merit to the designation well-known".

Comment: Having saod that, I fullt admit that Ron Gordon's solution is more elegant than my own!

Comment: I bet double against simple that no more than 5% percent of profesional mathematicians  know the quartic formula. Of course, one can follow its development as it is basic algebra...but it is an extremely complex formula and development. That it exists in the web and in some (not that many, by the way!) text books doesn't make it, imho, "well known"...not at all. I also can't see what's seminal in it about understanding anything of Galois theory: knowing that it exists could, perhaps be such.

Comment: In fact, 5% seems to be an overstatement...

Comment: This problem belongs to a foundation course in mathematics so I doubt that this is the solution my professors had in mind. But it's certainly a solution.